# Reading in a graph in C?

Tags: c, graph, nodes, edges

So say I have a graph that reads

```
6 7
1 2 -2
2 3 -1
3 1 -4
3 4 -2
3 5 -3
6 4 -1
6 5 -4
```

where the first line indicates the number of nodes and number of edges respectively, then the rest reads the edges and weight. I know how to read the input from this graph.

My question is, how would I read this graph's edges and weight without specifying the number of nodes (or anything) on the first line. For example, how would I read in this graph to do the same thing...

```
1 4 -4
2 3 3
1 2 -2
3 4 -2
2 1 1
```

Thanks!

```
Here is my current code

FILE *fin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        fscanf(fin, "%d", &n);
        e = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                fscanf(fin, "%d", &w);
                if (w != 0) {
                    edges[e].u = i;
                    edges[e].v = j;
                    edges[e].w = w;
                    ++e;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just read until the end of the file?

Comment: How are you reading the lines presently?  I.e., after you read that first line, how are you consuming the remaining lines?

Comment: Sorry I can't get this to format correctly. Right now I have
    `FILE *fin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        
          fscanf(fin, "%d", &n);
    e = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            fscanf(fin, "%d", &w);
            if (w != 0) {
                edges[e].u = i;
                edges[e].v = j;
                edges[e].w = w;
                ++e;
            }
        }`

@Floris @Eric

Comment: Just edited my original question to include my current code properly formatted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would create a linked list that grows dynamically with every node that is added - and keep going until the end of file. Lots of calls to `malloc` will do it. Unless you show how you are reading in your data now, and what your data structure is, it's hard to give you a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depends a little on your graph implementation and if you can dynamically insert nodes.  For each line, read the two nodes and if one or both don't currently exist in your graph you would need to insert them then insert the edge.  If you are using a matrix representation you would need to continually resize and copy the matrix (bad).  If you are using a list or queue representation then you would need to traverse each node to see if it was inserted already for each new line (bad, but less bad).  This is slightly better with an ordered list as you can just stop and insert whenever you get to a node with a higher number.  This implementation also does not require the nodes be consecutively named (i.e. a graph with node names 1, 2, 5, 19, 20202, 20203,...)